# why do I need to store the configuration setting in the Firebase Remote Config instead of using regular firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-remote-config

so currently I save my app setting in my firestore like this ?

[image]

it can work as I want, and it can be real time as well.

but recently I just learn about Firebase Remote Config, and it just basically to save key value pair on the cloud. and from the video I saw on youtube, the example is to store the configuration setting like the image above using Firebase Remote Config.

it sounds similar to firestore database in my opinion.

so I have 2 questions:

1. why do I need to store the setting in my firebase remote config ?
2. is it safe to store the API key in firebase remote config ? I want to save my Google map reverse geocoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. because Remote Config has [conditions, rules, and conditional values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#conditions_rules_and_conditional_values).
2. restrict a Maps API key to the fingerprints of the app's signing keys.

Comment: Remote Config also has a very nice console to build such conditions.

Comment: For #2: Reading the values from Remote Config is only marginally harder to find than when you have them in the compiled binary. Any values that are used in the client can be found by a sufficiently advanced malicious user.